# What is a set of overlapping sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

If I have a set $X$ and a set $Y$ and $\forall y \in Y : y \subseteq X \land \exists y_1, y_2 \in Y : y_1 \ne y_2 \land y_1 \cap y_2 \ne \{\}$, what is the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ called?

Comment: Why down vote? I was wondering how this would be expressed in a mathematically correct way. (Which now I know to be 'a family of subsets').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $Y$ is a family of subsets of $X$.

If you want to be specific about the fact $Y$ is not pairwise disjoint,

> $Y$ is not a partition of a subset of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

"A set of subsets of $X$ such that at least one element of $X$ is in two or more of them"?